# How to fix jQuery submenu accordion using nextUntil() and not()?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, accordion

I'm trying to use jQuery's nextUntil() but the other parent divs are closing when I click the child divs. I wanted to use the .not() before the nextUntil function.

I'm trying to achieve a correct way of hiding and showing child divs. Thanks

```
$('.content').click(function() {
    $(this).not('.head').nextUntil('.content').toggle('slow');
    $('.subcontentchild').hide();

    return false;
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pys5T/8/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify multiple selectors separated by `,`:

```
$('.content').click(function() {
    $(this).nextUntil('.content,.head').toggle('slow');
    $('.subcontentchild').hide();

    return false;
});
```

See [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pys5T/11/)

Comment: Thanks Shimon. However if I add a 3rh head div, the showing and hiding of the parent and child is incorrect. I just added this:
http://jsfiddle.net/pys5T/10/

Comment: Thanks again Shimon. If I clicked the "2-3-1 Visitor" the 3rd parent div disappears.

Comment: Nice! Thanks Shimon. I was confused at nextUntil(). I should have added the content and the subcontent. Cheers! :D